# Sublime Text preview fail

Tags: sublime-text, ghostscript, latextools

I have some problems in converting pdf to png, in Sublime Text editor. It has an error message: `ERROR: Failed to convert pdf to png to preview.` To check the error report, it shows only one text as below.

I have found several solutions from Google, and it seems that there is some problems in Ghostscript. [Here](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1148#issuecomment-308126813) are the link I found.

I installed the latest Ghostscript from official site, but I need to renew the path of Ghostscript from system check of LaTeXTools, and I cannot modify it.

Hence, my questions are as following:

1. Is this correct solution to solve equation preview problem by reinstalling GS?
2. If it is, is my work correct? How do I modify LaTeXTools SystemCheck?
3. Are there any easy solutions for my problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing "Check System" and make sure everything is properly installed? I found this comment on github very useful: https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1148#issuecomment-429915037

Basically, somehow you need to set the .\bin folder (e.g. "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.24\bin") of the Ghostscript into the PATH in environment variables and it would work.

Hope it helps

Comment: In my case the system check showed that ghostscript was installed, but Mullwer's answer caused me to run ghostscript, which gave an error ''Can't find initialization file gs_init.p", which was solved by the SO answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150928/1299362.  So thanks for the hint.